# How to add a tooltip to a Form API field?

Tags: forms

I have a field defined like that:

```
'name' => array(
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 30,
  '#maxlength' => 45,
  '#default_value' => $item->Name,
  '#description' => t("Item's name, no longer than 45 characters."),
),
```

How can I turn the description into a tooltip that will appear when user keeps mouse cursor over form element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution is to use [`#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) attribute to provide form element with [HTML title attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp), like that:

```
'name' => array(
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 30,
  '#maxlength' => 45,
  '#default_value' => $item->Name,
  // '#description' => t("Item's name, no longer than 45 characters."),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'title' => t("Item's name, no longer than 45 characters."),
  )
),
```